# Custom route for MVC controller in a market place package is not working

Tags: mvc, routing

I am working on a marketplace package that services some analytics data via MVC controllers. But when testing I am finding several implementations of DI that cause my route to fail on the site.

One of the errors is

```
[ExceptionWrapper: The controller for path '/apis/v1/VisitorDetails' was not found or does not implement IController.]

[ControllerCreationException: Could not create controller: 'Visitor'.
```

From one of Sean Holmesby's post, it looks like the DI is not letting my controller register correctly. But with his answer, I have no ability nor want to modify the websites DependencyResolver.

http://www.seanholmesby.com/safe-dependency-injection-for-mvc-and-webapi-within-sitecore/

I am registering the routes via the Initialize pipeline.

```cs
public class RegisterCustomRoute : Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes
{
    private const string BASE_ROUTE = "apis";
    private const string API_VERSION = "/v1";

    public override void Process(PipelineArgs args)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
            "VisitorData",
            BASE_ROUTE + API_VERSION + "/VisitorDetails",
            new { controller = "Visitor", action = "VisitorDetailsJson" });

        RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
            "ClearVisitorSession",
            BASE_ROUTE + API_VERSION + "/ClearVisitorSession",
            new { controller = "Visitor", action = "ClearVisitorSession" });
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make my MVC route work consistently, or should I move the route inside sitecore or just stay away from routes in marketplace packages?

Update: Added pipeline config and controller.

```xml
<pipelines>
    <initialize>
        <processor type="Bonfire.Analytics.Dto.Pipelines.Initialize.RegisterCustomRoute, Bonfire.Analytics.Dto"
                   patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes, Sitecore.Mvc']"/>
    </initialize>
</pipelines>
```

And here is the controller.

```cs
public class VisitorController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult VisitorDetailsJson()
    {
        var vi = new VisitorInfo();
        var trackerDto = vi.GetTrackerDto();

        return Json(trackerDto, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult ClearVisitorSession()
    {
        Session.Abandon();

        return Json("Session Cleared");
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please add a lines from your config file for this pipeline? And yes, the same exception will be thrown if sitecore simply cannot instantiate your controller

Comment: I added the pipeline config and the controller. I tried SitecoreController as well.

Comment: This code works fine in a clean install of Sitecore, both with and without Dependency Injection configured. When exactly are you seeing this code stop working? When you install a particular module?

Comment: It works everywhere I put it other than Jets.sitecore project. It seems to have something special that doesn't let the controller get created.

Comment: I was reading some posts that maybe the System.Web.Mvc or Sitecore.Mvc versions could be different than the ones i built with. But they are the same as my version of Jets.

Comment: @dnstommy can you check how exactly the Jets.sitecore project configures the mvc controller factory and dependency resolver? it might be causing your problem